# Why do jquery.lazy not work when images are loaded with jquery load()?

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I am using jquery.lazy plugin to load images in a gallery.

http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/

It works great if I do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lazy Load</title>
<script src="jquery/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.lazy/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script>    
$(function() {
    $('.lazy').lazy({
      effect: "fadeIn",
      effectTime: 2000,
      threshold: 0
    });
});
</script>

<img class="lazy" data-src="1.jpg" />
<img class="lazy" data-src="100.jpg" />

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to load all 100 images in the gallery like this.

```
$("#id").load("file_that_load_all_images.php");
```

But jquery.lazy do not work if I do that. It seems that it will never be called. How do I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is called on doc.ready `$(function() {`

doc.ready fires before your `$("#id").load()` completes (which itself is *probably* in doc.ready)

`$(selector)` is not a "live" search and only returns matches at the time it runs.

Call `$(".lazy")` after your images have loaded, using `$.load`s "complete" callback, eg:

```
$(function() {
    $("#id").load("file_that_load_all_images.php", function() {
        $('.lazy').lazy({
          effect: "fadeIn",
          effectTime: 2000,
          threshold: 0
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried your code but jquery.lazy is not called. I can see the images but not with any lazy loading.